# ASP.NET MVC - is Session["Layout"] some kind of a predefined word?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was using `Session["Layout"]` to determine what layout does user have. But some werid stuff started to happen. Sometimes on my route: `forums/{action}/{variable}` it was placed in the `action` space, sometimes it made my controllers execute twice, first round with normal route parameters, second with `action` replaced with `Session["Layout"]`!

When i stopped using `Session["Layout"]`, and instead used `Session["myLayout"]` everything was normal again. Is the `Session["Layout"]` some kind of a predefined keyword or something?

Answer (score 1):

In short - no.

Asp.Net MVC has absolutely no dependency on session whatsoever (you can disable Session completely and MVC will work just fine).  Therefore I would suggest that any weirdness you observe when you introduce session is connected to your code alone.

Of course - any components you use (nuget packages and such) might require session; I can't speak for those.

Comment: But, i just searched whole project for a word Session["Layout"], and there is no usage of that. :| I have no idea why it did what it did...